# Spring cannot find class which exists in classpath

Tags: java, spring, maven

I have two projects and projectB depends projectA.  I use Maven to do it:

```
parent  
|- pom.xml  // I use <modules> here to add two projects in.  
|- MyProjectA  
|   `- pom.xml  
|- MyProjectB  
    `- pom.xml
```

Now I can import projectA to projectB java code and use the classes in projectA.
But when I try to use spring for prokectB as below:

```
<bean id="test" class="com.company.common.util.PropertyUtils"/>  // The class is inside projectA.
```

Spring says ClassNotFoundException.
Any ideads?  Thanks.

Comment: Is it web app? if it is do you see the class exists in the classes folder?

Answer (score 1):

You can directly add projectA dependency into projectB pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>common.group</groupId>
        <artifactId>project-a-artifact</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

See also [How can I create an executable JAR with dependencies using Maven?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574594/how-can-i-create-an-executable-jar-with-dependencies-using-maven) to check more possible solutions